# How to sum distances between data points in a dataset using (Py)Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset of locations in Lat/Lon format of users in a time period. I would like to calculate the distance these users traveled. Sample dataset:

> | Timestamp|                User| Latitude|Longitude|
>   |1462838468|49B4361512443A4DA...|39.777982|-7.054599|
>   |1462838512|49B4361512443A4DA...|39.777982|-7.054599|
>   |1462838389|49B4361512443A4DA...|39.777982|-7.054599|
>   |1462838497|49B4361512443A4DA...|39.777982|-7.054599|
>   |1465975885|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1457723815|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177322|-7.426781|
>   |1457897289|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177922|-7.447443|
>   |1457899229|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177922|-7.447443|
>   |1457972626|405C238E25FE0B9E7...| 37.18059| -7.46128|
>   |1458062553|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177322|-7.426781|
>   |1458241825|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.178172|-7.444512|
>   |1458244457|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.178172|-7.444512|
>   |1458412513|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177322|-7.426781|
>   |1458412292|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|37.177322|-7.426781|
>   |1465197963|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465202192|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465923817|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465923766|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465923748|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|
>   |1465923922|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|37.118362|-8.205041|

I have thought of using a custom aggregator function but it seems there is no Python support for this. Moreover the operations need to be done on adjacent points in a specific order, so I don't know if a custom aggregator would work.

I have also looked at `reduceByKey` but the operator requirements don't seem to be met by the distance function.

Is there a way to perform this operation in an efficient manner in Spark?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like a job for window functions. Assuming we define distance as:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import acos, cos, sin, lit, toRadians

def dist(long_x, lat_x, long_y, lat_y):
    return acos(
        sin(toRadians(lat_x)) * sin(toRadians(lat_y)) + 
        cos(toRadians(lat_x)) * cos(toRadians(lat_y)) * 
            cos(toRadians(long_x) - toRadians(long_y))
    ) * lit(6371.0)
```

you can define window as:

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().partitionBy("User").orderBy("Timestamp")
```

and compute distances between consecutive observations using `lag`:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag

df.withColumn("dist", dist(
    "longitude", "latitude",
    lag("longitude", 1).over(w), lag("latitude", 1).over(w)
).alias("dist"))
```

After that you can perform standard aggregation.

Comment: FTR, the distance formula is the equirectangular distance approximation? I had looked at the Haversine Formula but this seems different. Btw, you have duplicated the parameter "long_y" in the method declaration.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. It should be the [great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

Comment: No, thank you, it seems to be working. Another question, what are the units of the result of this distance function? Kms, right? At least the R seems to be in Kms.

Comment: I've noticed that the distance function is not very numerically stable when calculating the distance between equal coordinates. For example: Latitude=41.239548, Longitude=-8.685635 gives `nan`. Is it possible to add a conditional branch to the distance function to return 0 when the coordinates are the same or would it be better to filter at the dataframe level these rows that have the same coordinates as the next row?

Comment: Indeed it is not numerically stable and this is a reason why Haversine formula is usually preferred. I just don't remember the latter one by heart. Regarding conditionals you can use `pyspark.sql.functions.when(cond, x).otherwise(y)`  construct.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with `F.when((F.col(lat_x) == lat_y) & (F.col(long_x) == long_y), F.lit(0.0)).otherwise...`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As a side note, the result is in km.